# ConTeXt: Fill full page with image, disregarding page layout

Tags: graphics, context

## Background

Looking to create a three-column document with images that fill entire pages, while the text has a different page layout. Both the images and the text pages should have the same total dimensions.

[image: Output]

## Problem

The issue is that the image doesn't fill the entire page, even though the ratio of the page size (4:1) is the same as the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiEdE.jpg) size (4:1), as shown here:

[image: Cat columns]

## Code

A fairly minimal snippet to reproduce the problem:

```
\definepapersize[ImpactsPageSize][
  width=400mm,
  height=100mm,
]

\definelayout[ImpactsPageLayout][
  backspace=5mm,
  cutspace=5mm,
  width=390mm,
  height=85mm,
  topspace=5mm,
  header=0mm,
  footer=0mm,
]

\setuppapersize[ImpactsPageSize]
\setuplayout[ImpactsPageLayout]

\setuphead[chapter][
  header=empty,
  footer=empty,
  number=no,
  page=yes,
]

\setupexternalfigures[
  location={local,default,global},
  maxwidth=\makeupwidth,
  width=\makeupwidth,
]

\let\oldexternalfigure\externalfigure
\def\externalfigure[#1]{%
  \startTEXpage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,align=middle]
    \oldexternalfigure[#1][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]%
  \stopTEXpage
}

\starttext
    \chapter[title={One}]

    \startcolumns[n=3]
        \input knuth
        \input knuth
        \input knuth
    \stopcolumns

    {\externalfigure[https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiEdE.jpg]}
\stoptext
```

## Constraints

The `externalfigure` snippet is generated by pandoc and therefore must not be changed or altered in any way:

```
{\externalfigure[https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiEdE.jpg]}
```

## Question

What do I need to change to make the image fill the full page independently of the page layout of the text pages? (That is, how do I eliminate the white borders shown in the example images while maintaining the image aspect ratio?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your document contains a `maxwidth` setting for all included graphic. When you have a image which is wider than this value it is scaled down to the maximum value.

The example below shows a case where this setup is useful to keep the width of the images limited.

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]

\setuppapersize [A6] [A5,landscape]

\setuparranging[2SIDE]

\showframe [text] [text]

\starttext

\externalfigure [a] [width=1.1\makeupwidth]

\page

\setupexternalfigures [maxwidth=\makeupwidth]

\externalfigure [b] [width=1.1\makeupwidth]

\stoptext
```

[image: Example maxwidth limit]

The wiki's [layout page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout) shows various ways that the makeupwidth can be calculated. Specifically:

> `\makeupwidth` is normally same as `\textwidth`, but it can be different, for example in columns.